# solve First order partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

we need to solve this equation:

$$(x^2 + y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + 2xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = (x + y)^3 z$$

the general solution to this equation is :

$$\frac{dx}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{dy}{2xy} = \frac{dz}{(x+y)^3z}$$

the final general answer is :

$$F(c_1) = c_2$$

that $c_1$ and $c_2$ is the constant comes from the above equation. now the question is how to find $c_1$ and $c_2$

Comment: Can you show us what you've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{dx}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{dy}{2xy} = \frac{dz}{(x+y)^3z}$ is not the general solution, but is the characteristic system of differential equations.

HINT :

To find the first characteristic equation observe that :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{xdx-ydy}{x(x^2 + y^2)-2xy^2} =\frac{xdx-ydy}{x(x^2 - y^2)}$$
and solve the first ODE (simplify and integrate with change of variable $t=x^2-y^2$ ): 
$$\frac{xdx-ydy}{x(x^2 - y^2)} = \frac{dy}{2xy}$$

To find the second characteristic equation, observe that

$$\frac{dx}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{dy}{2xy} =\frac{dx+dy}{x^2 + y^2+2xy}$$
and solve the second ODE (change of variable $t=x+y$ ) : 
$$\frac{dx+dy}{x^2 + y^2+2xy}= \frac{dz}{(x+y)^3z}$$

Answer (score 0):

initially we will be getting

$ \frac{ \mathrm dx + \mathrm dy + \mathrm dz } {\mathrm (x^2+y^2) + \mathrm (2xy) + \mathrm (z(x+y)^3 )} $ ----> eqn (1)

we need to decide the factors to arrive at this condition

$ \mathrm A(x^2+y^2) + B(2xy) + C((x+y)^3)z = 0 $

i.e.
$ \frac{ \mathrm A dx + \mathrm B dy + \mathrm C dz } {\mathrm A (x^2+y^2) + \mathrm B (2xy) + \mathrm C (z(x+y)^3 )} $ ----> eqn (2)

case 1: we can substitute A=-(xz+yz) , B= -(xz-yz) ,C=1

so the equation becomes,

$ \mathrm dx(-(xz+yz)) + dy (-(xz+yz)) + dz = C1 $

on integrating them separately,we get

$ C1= \mathrm (x^2 + y^2 + 4xy - 2)z $

case 2: we can substitue A=(xz+yz), B=(xz+yz) , C=-1

$ C2 = \mathrm (-x^2 - y^2 - 4xy +2)z $

so $ C1=-C2 $

Answer (score 0):

Solve PDE
$$(x^2 + y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + 2xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = (x + y)^3 z$$

- After change $\;u=\log z, \;z=e^u\;$ we get 
  $$(x^2 + y^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 2xy\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = (x + y)^3$$
- After next change $\xi=x+y,\;\eta=x-y\;$ we have
  $$\xi^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} + \eta^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta} = \xi^3$$
- Particular solution is $u_p=\frac{\xi^2}{2}$. Complementary solution is
  $u_c=f(\frac1\xi-\frac1\eta)$. Then 
  $$u=u_c+u_p=f\left(\frac1\xi-\frac1\eta\right)+\frac{\xi^2}{2}$$
- Final solution of PDE is

$$z=e^{f\left(\frac1\xi-\frac1\eta\right)+\frac{\xi^2}{2}}=
e^{f\left(\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac1{x-y}\right)+\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}\\=e^{\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}F\left(\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac1{x-y}\right)
$$